# Intermittent issue before browser cookies clearance getting 502 Service Temporarily Unavailable & after browser cookies clearance 503 BadGateway Nginx

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, cookies

We are having kubernetes pod with running two containers (Nginx container and Application container) inside it. We have defined nginx configuration as a config map along with deployment.yaml file and deploying application in each sprint with latest code.

But while testing it, we are getting intermittent issue and  before browser cookies clearance getting 502 Service Temporarily Unavailable & after browser cookies clearance 503 BadGateway Nginx errors respectively.

we have defined large_client_header_buffers 4 16k; from default values in nginx.conf to avoid any issue with cookies. Still it is not resolved and still getting 502 Service Temporarily Unavailable & after browser cookies clearance 503 BadGateway Nginx errors. I'll highly appreciate if anybody can suggest a solution to overcome over it.

Here is the file I am using for deployment:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{APP_NAME}}-nginx
  namespace: {{NAME_SPACE}}
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    user  nginx;
    worker_processes  1;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }
    http {
        server_tokens off;
        include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
        sendfile        on;
        #tcp_nopush     on;
        keepalive_timeout  65;
        gzip  on;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    }
  default.conf: |
    map $http_user_agent $ignore_ua {
      default                 1;
      "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" 0;
      "kube-probe/1.21+"      0;
    }
    
    server {
       listen 3001 ssl;
       ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/ssc/ssc.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/ssc/ssc.key;
       server_name         localhost;
       proxy_buffer_size          128k;
       proxy_buffers              4 256k;
       proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
       location ~* ^/(api/.+) {
          add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow, nosnippet, noarchive";
          proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/$1$is_args$args;
          access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined if=$ignore_ua;
       }
       location / {
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
          proxy_hide_header Expires;
          proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires;
          proxy_intercept_errors on;
          add_header Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate";
          proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
       }
    }
```